# Python Healpy Mollview scatter subplots show up in all subfigures

Tags: python, healpy

I'm trying to plot two subplots of hp.mollview projections with scatterplots, The first
scatterplot shows up in the correct subfigure. But the second scatterplot shows up in
both subfigures.

the code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import healpy as hp
import h5py

#generate random angular values
#1st scatter plot:
A=2*np.pi*(2*np.random.rand(200)-1)
B=np.pi/2*(2*np.random.rand(200)-1)
#2nd scatter plot:
C=2*np.pi*(2*np.random.rand(200)-1)
D=np.pi/2*(2*np.random.rand(200)-1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(12.5,10))
fig.tight_layout(pad=.0001,h_pad=.0001,w_pad=.0001)

plt.axes(ax[0])
hp.mollview(None,cbar=None,title=None,hold=True)
hp.graticule()
hp.projscatter(A,B,color='red',s=30)

plt.axes(ax[1])
hp.mollview(None,cbar=None,title=None,hold=True)
hp.graticule()
hp.projscatter(C,D,color='blue',s=30)
plt.show()
```

I tried so many things to reformulate e.g. with the subplots(121), subplots(122)
format, but the second scatterplot somehow show up in both figures. This normally works and the issue is with mollview and projscatter since they can be somewhat nonconventional. There is one almost identical unanswered question about this on GitHub. Other than that I didn't find anything.

I ended up with a quick fix by saving the figures separately and plotting with imgread instead,
but why does the second scatterplot behave like this?

Comment: I am running into the same problem now, did you find a solution to the issue and can you share it?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Will share if I find a solution.

Comment: I found a way to do something like what you need to do, but completely without healpy, instead I used the mollweide projection of matplotlib. So you don't get the problem stated above. You will find my code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77887624/5838180

Comment: `plt.axes(ax[0])` is probably not what you want, as it creates a new axis on top of the older one.  `plt.sca(ax[0])` ("set current ax") would make `ax[0]` the "current" subplot.  Also, `fig.tight_layout(...)` is normally called at the end (just before `plt.show()`) as it takes the label texts into account.

Comment: @JohanC If your solution is to substitue `plt.axes(ax[0])` with `plt.sca(ax[0])` - I just tried it and it ends with the same slawed behaviour. Can you suggest another solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I asked one of the main contributors to `healpy`, he [answered](https://github.com/healpy/healpy/issues/895#issuecomment-1920075604) on github and following his advice by using [`newprojview`](https://healpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/newvisufunc_example.html) I created these great subplots with the scatter-subplots showing nominal behaviour:

```
m = np.zeros(hp.nside2npix(32))
m2= np.random.random(hp.nside2npix(32))

projview(
    m,
    # cmap="planck",
    graticule=True,
    graticule_labels=True,
    sub=221,
    override_plot_properties={"figure_width": 13, "figure_size_ratio": 0.53},
    cbar=None,
);
plt.scatter(np.deg2rad([0, -30, 30]), np.deg2rad([0,0,0]), color="red", s=80);

projview(
    m,
    # cmap="planck",
    graticule=True,
    graticule_labels=True,
    cbar=None,
    sub=222,
);
plt.tight_layout();
plt.scatter(np.deg2rad([90, 90, 90]), np.deg2rad([45,-45,0]), color="black", s=80);

projview(
    m2,
    cmap="planck",
    sub=223,
);
plt.scatter(np.deg2rad([0, -30, 30]), np.deg2rad([30,30,30]), color="green", s=80);

projview(
    m2,
    cmap="planck",
    sub=224,
);
plt.tight_layout();
plt.scatter(np.deg2rad([-30, -30, -30]), np.deg2rad([45,-45,0]), color="white", s=80);
```

[image]